# Django: Return queryset and string

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, httpresponse

In Django, is it possible to  make a HttpResponse which is a combination of a queryset and a text string?

I imagine something like this

```
objs = ModelName.objects.all()

text = "Some text"

allData = ??? #Some kind of operation (json.dumps, serializers, or ...) that combines the two

return HttpResonse(allData,content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both in a dictionary, for example:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from json import loads as jloads

objs = ModelName.objects.all()
text = 'Some text'

allData = {
    'objs': jloads(serialize('json', objs)),
    'text': text
}

return JsonResponse(allData)
```

The data is thus a JSON object with two keys: `objs` that will contain the serialized queryset, and `text` that will contain the value in `text`.

Comment: Wow instant reply:-) Thanks works perfectly after adding a comma: allData = {
    'objs': jloads(serialize('json', objs)),
    'text': text
}